# Spring 3.2 and Quartz Scheduler

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, configuration-files

I have an Spring application to maintain that has Quartz Scheduler configured in an applicationContex-quartz.xml file.  A SchedulerFactoryBean is defined with a list of 4 triggers.

One of the triggers i have to modify is a CronTrigger with a simple schedule where it's ran the 15th of the month at 3AM.  I need to take into account of some special holidays.  I'm aware i can use the Calendar class.  My question really is how do I configure it in the xml file?  I only want one of the triggers to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If those special holidays can be expressed into a single [cron expression](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html) you shouldn't have problems.

If those special holidays can't be expressed into a single [cron expression](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html) and you don't want to modify the following:

```
<bean id="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
<property name="triggers">
    <list>
        <ref bean="cronTrigger1" />
        <ref bean="cronTrigger2" />
        <ref bean="cronTrigger3" />
        <ref bean="cronTrigger4" />
    </list>
</property>
```

I think you can't do what you want because in a `CronTriggerBean`:

```
<bean id="cronTrigger1" ="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="quartzSchedulerSpecialHolidays" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="abracadabra" />
</bean>
```

you can associate only one `jobDetail` to one `cronExpression`.